# as much as I do? - what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

**I love him dearly and he loves me as much as I do.**

What does this sentence mean?

1. He loves me as much as I love myself.
2. He loves me as much as I love him.

Comment: It means the person who said it is a *learner* who doesn't speak English very well. Native speakers wouldn't say this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for the "meaning" of an invalid utterance

Answer (score 2):

It means whatever the speaker meant it to mean.

Logically, it means *as much as I love myself*, but (unless there's a rather special context) that is unlikely, so the speaker probably intends *as much as I love him*.

Don't expect logical consistency from speakers.

Answer (score 0):

It could mean both alternatives but #2 seems more likely.